# Beacon NRF52832 read temp/humidity value from a SHT30 sensor assembled

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, esp32

I have a esp32 microcontroller and I trying to read a temperature/humidity value from a NRF52832 beacon with a SHT30 sensor (http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/682/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT3x_Datasheet_digital-971521.pdf) but there is no service in BLE advertising.
After a long time I found the "manufacturer data" which change after each connection on BLE server.
My doubt is if the read bytes of the sensor is on the "manufacturer data" and how I can extract it.

Example of an output "manufacturer data":
59000215fda5069300010002d8 **0eee14362c196d66dfac1500** -> this part changes every connection

I tried convert this hex values to big endian uint16 and found some interesting values, but nothing right.

Thanks :)

**Edit:**
I put this datasheet because shows the way how SHT30 sends data in this format (page 10):
[Data send format from the SHT30 sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAHCi.png)

Beacon link: [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/NRF52832-posicionamento-Ibeacon-beacon-da-esta-o-Base-Anti-lost-Perif-rica-m-dulo-Bluetooth-5/32954025507.html)

Comment: The data sheet attached won't help find an answer.  The format of the BLE manufacturer advertisement depends on the firmware inside the ESP32.  With proper firmware, the temperature data could be put into that advertisement you are seeing.  Without proper firmware, it might not be at all.  Figuring out which is the case means (1) getting the documentation about the firmware, or (2) trying to reverse engineer it yourself.  With only one data point of advertised bytes, it is unlikely that anyone else in this forum will have enough information to reverse engineer it.

Comment: I don't know if I was clear.
The temperature/humidity's service should be on the beacon, not on esp32.
I connect the beacon and receive from him this "manufacturer data". This value don't should be constant? Unless I change some data on beacon, like major and minor values. When I convert some final bytes and use in the equations on datasheet I reach interesting values.

Comment: I connect the beacon on android phone too, and the beacon does not advertise the service of temperature. I think the data is in "manufacturer data".

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question -- I now understand that the firmware that must advertise the temperature or expose the GATT service to get the temperature is inside the  NRF52832 not the ESP32.  But the remainder of my comment is still valid.  You need documentation of how the custom NRF52832 firmware does this.   Does it expose a GATT service?  Does it send it in the manufacturer data?  Why do you think either might be true?  Did you read this somewhere?  If so, where?

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation @davidgyoung.
I tried to contact the seller but didn't respond me. So I don't have access to the specific documentation for my beacon.
There is no service to the temperature, only a few others like generic access (0x1800), current time service (0x1805) and others, what I suposed to be default for a BLE beacon.
Reading the SHT30 datasheet and observating the varying bytes of the "manufacturer data" I imagine that can be the answer.
If you have a knowledge about the BLE library, I can explain the code to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to "reverse engineer" the manufacturer data in search for the temperature readings, you'll need to know how the temperature is encoded/calculated for that sensor. In other words, how to convert the raw data/bytes from the sensor into an actual value.

I found this in the [code samples for SHT3x](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/13_Sample_Codes_Software/Humidity_Sensors/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT3x_Sample_Code.pdf):

```
static ft SHT3X_CalcTemperature(u16t rawValue)
{
  // calculate temperature [°C]
  // T = -45 + 175 * rawValue / (2^16-1)
  return 175.0f * (ft)rawValue / 65535.0f - 45.0f;
}
```

With that in mind, I'd try something like this:

1. Try each consecutive pair of bytes in the manufacturer data.

   - for `0eee14362c196d66dfac1500`, that'd be `0e` + `ee`, then `ee` + `14`, etc.
2. Convert the two bytes into uint16. Since we don't know the endianness, you'd need to try both MSB and LSB.

   - for example, for `0e` + `ee`, try both `0eee` and `ee0e`
3. Use that uint16 as the `rawValue` for the function above to get the temperature.

Then you can see if any of the output you get actually resembles temperature readings.

Comment: That's was exactly what I tried to do.
After some days of tries, I found the composition of this "manufacturer data":

manufacturerId | subType & Length | proximityUUID | major | minor | signalPower
         1B                           3B                       16B             2B        2B           1B

The minor and major values, converted to big endian uint16, shows a interesting result. I don't have another way to calculate the temperature and humidity, but when I get this uint16 values converted  and put in my code (same as you posted) the results looks like the weather prediction.

Comment: , not sure if there's anything else you could do then … other than trying to find the programming pins on that beacon and flashing your own firmware (;

Comment: I don't have skill to this for now, so I think my problem is partially resolved.
Thank you :)